# QFile::open fails with unicode filename

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, filenames

I want to open a file with QFile::Open where my file name is unicode:

```
           QString fname(QFile::decodeName("D:/أحدالأنشطة.txt"));
           QFile qFile(fname);

           bool b=qFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
           if(b)
           {
               FILE* filedesc = fdopen(qFile.handle(), "rb");
               if(filedesc!=NULL)
               {
                   char* nb=(char*)malloc(2*sizeof(char));
                   qDebug()<<"opened ";
                   size_t size=fread(nb,sizeof(char),2,filedesc);
                   fclose(filedesc);
                   qDebug()<<"filedesc closed size "<<size<<"nb "<<QString::fromAscii(nb,2);
                   nb=NULL;
                   free(nb);

               }else qDebug()<<"filedesc failed   error"<<strerror(errno);


            }else
                qDebug()<<"qFile failed   error"<<strerror(errno);
```

It failed and I get:

```
qFile failed   error No error
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use the [`QFile::error()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfile.html#error) function to get the cause of failure.

Comment: it returns 5 so it's filename syntax error(The syntax of the file name, directory name, or volume is incorrect).

Comment: And what if you select this file with QFileDialog? Does it open?

Comment: So wired it opened by `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` and when I pass the returned qstring it works !!!! so how to fix this I don't want to open a QFileDialoge.

Comment: It's never a good idea to use 8-bit, non-ASCII literals in the source code. Not all compiler properly handles text encoding even when you specify it. Why do you need to include the hardcoded 8-bit filename?

Comment: @StephenChu I need to support any given filename what ever the encoding ...

Comment: Yes. We all do. But why is the filename hardcoded in the source? If it's a localized filename of some common files, the localized name should be in a translation resource. If it's just a private file known only to you, name it in ASCII.

Comment: @StephenChu this an example of my code , in fact the file name is captured by another function (that watches a directory and notify if a file was added and send the name as WCHAR [] ), so I resolved  my problem by calling winapi methods that handle an unicode file name :), thank you for your time.

Comment: If it's in WCHAR[] than just use `QString filename((QChar*) yourWcharData);`

Comment: @StephenChu finally it works with `(QChar*)` casting :)) thank you, you can write your last comment as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is in `WCHAR` array than just use `QString filename((QChar*) yourWcharData);`

Answer (score 1):

If your source file is UTF-8 encoded, then you might be able to do this:

```
QString fname(QString::fromUtf8("D:/أحدالأنشطة.txt"));
```

If it's UTF-16, then:

```
QString fname(QString::fromUtf16("D:/أحدالأنشطة.txt"));
```

If the source file is neither UTF-8 not UTF-16, try this instead:

```
QString fname(QString::fromLocal8Bit("D:/أحدالأنشطة.txt"));
```

If that also doesn't work, then you need to find out the character set your editor is using.

Comment: Thank you Nikos for your time I really appreciate it,both didn't work ,please how find out character set of my editor (I'am using QtCreator)?

Comment: @oumaya In Tools->Option->Text Editor, in the "Behavior" tab, there should be a "Default encoding" item list that shows the current default encoding.

Comment: I tried `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
         QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForUtfText("UTF-8"));` but in vain same problem.

Comment: No, that won't convert existing text. I'm not sure what Windows uses by default (I assume you're on Windows?). Maybe it's UTF-16. So try QString::fromUtf16().

Comment: @NikosC. note that fromLocal8Bit depends from envoirment where application is launched. I would change file encoding to utf-8, then type string in utf8 encoding again with `QString::fromUtf8(...)`

Comment: @KamilKlimek That's not a good idea IMO, since you lose compatibility with other Windows editors. It's best to stick to the native encoding of your OS.

Comment: @NikosC. It's bad idea to use "fromLocal8Bit" as it uses runtime encoding, not compile time. So if you compile char array in cp1250 encoding and then use same software on machine with cp1252 encoding you will break your software. To be honest. Sticking with "current machine encoding" is bad when you're developing cross platform software. You will never be "compatible" with all editors.